# API monitor does not always return name of DLL module

Tags: windows, dll, hook, monitoring

I'm not sure I need to ask this question here, it's not really a programming question, but. They have their own forum, but it's no longer active.
I use the API monitor tool developed by rohitab to monitor API calls from malware and benign processes. However, in all cases I get results like the image below.

What surprises me is that in most cases the name of the module is returned, but also in many cases the name of the module is simply the name of the process. For example, PathFindExtensionW is part of Shlwapi.dll, but why is the name of the process returned as the name of the module and not Shlwapi.dll? The situation is similar with user32.dll, for example. For some functions, "User32" is returned as the name of the module, while for others the name is "re.exe", i.e. the name of the process is returned, while the functions in question are also part of User32.

[image]g...

Comment: Read the API Monitor documentation. It is "the name of the DLL that **made** the API call."